# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void WordsTranslation_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WordTranslation wordTranslation = sender as WordTranslation;

        WordsFlowLayOutPanel.Hide();
        ShowWordsButton.Enabled = true;
        int Y = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int yButton = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i += 2)
        {
            NewLabels.Add(new Label());
            NewLabels.Add(new Label());
            NewButtons.Add(new Button());
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    NewLabels[i].Text = "Тип:";
                    NewLabels[i].Name = "TypeLabel";
                    NewLabels[i + 1].Text = wordTranslation.Name; // Ошибка тут
```

System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

wordTranslation было null.

Comment: Значит не удалось привести `sender` к типу `WordTranslation`

Comment: Кто у вас sender?

Comment: @CrazyElf если я правильно понял вопрос, wordTranslation - это UserControl

Comment: Замените первую строчку на `WordTranslation wordTranslation = (WordTranslation)sender;` - будет другое исключение, которое скажет вам, в чем дело.

Comment: @aepot помогло, спасибо, понял в чем проблема